# Characterization of CF languages closed under circular shifts

Tags: reference-request, context-free

Along the same lines as what was asked in this post:
[Is there a simple characterization of regular languages closed under circular shifts?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53827/3247)

Are there simple characterizations/properties of Context Free languages that are closed under circular shifts? ($xy \in L \Leftrightarrow yx \in L$)

A simple characterization could be:

- put the grammar $G$ in Greibach Normal form
- if $P_i \equiv S_i \to a_i \,X_{i_1}...X_{i_n}$ are the productions from the start symbol $S$
- then $L$ is closed under circular shift if and only if

$L = L(G) \cap L(G')$

where $G'$ is obtained from $G$ replacing each production $P_i$ from the start symbol with:

$S'_i \to  X_{i_1}...X_{i_n} \, a_i$